# Replace certain characters in the dataframe python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get rid of ',' to print out just the number

```
bitcoin['Volume'].replace(',', '')
```

outputs

```
0        9,926,540,000
1        7,652,090,000
2        8,744,010,000
3        8,660,880,000
4        7,296,160,000
5        9,062,540,000
6        7,909,820,000
7        5,696,720,000
8        6,256,440,000
9        6,122,190,000
10       7,780,960,000
```

but it's not working for some reason. I did inplace = True

```
test = bitcoin['Volume'].replace(',', '', inplace=True)
print(test)
None
```

prints nothing.. What is going on???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test = bitcoin['Volume'].str.replace(',', '')
```

Easy fix... I did .str before .replace and it works

```
0        9926540000
1        7652090000
2        8744010000
3        8660880000
4        7296160000
5        9062540000
.
.
.
```